# Calling firebase function from firebase web SDK , No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I know this question is asked a lot but I have tried everything and my backend code looks correct to me. Is it my frontend that is preventing this? I was thinking that using the cors middleware that this would solve the problem.

Frontend Code:

```
var getCustomToken = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getCustomToken');

getCustomToken({id: 50}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error', error);
});
```

Firebase Function:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

// Automatically allow cross-origin requests
app.use(cors(({origin: true})));

// routes
app.get('getCustomToken/:id', (req, res) => getCustomToken(req, res));


// get custom token from evalExpert user id.
exports.getCustomToken = functions.https.onRequest( async (req, res) => {

    res.status(200).send();

});
```

Error Message:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Comment: Unfortunately my reputation isn't high enough to reopen this incorrectly flagged question, but your problem is caused by expecting a [Callable Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) on the client but defining a [HTTPS Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) on the server. The two are incompatible with each other.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. Changed onRequest to onCall and it sorted the issue.